# Model not being saved (Fixtures)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, fixtures

my recors are not being saved to the database after being created. I'm just using fixtures. I can see the model on the Ember addon when creating it in the form, but after hitting save, they dissappear and nothing happens. Also, when I select an item on the model.genre select input nothing happens.
This is what I did:

**/router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('books', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('book', {path: '/books/:book_id'});
  this.resource('genre', {path: '/genres/:genre_id'});

  this.resource('reviews', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

**reviews/new.hbs**

```
<div class='row'>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="book_title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Book Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          {{input class="form-control" id="book_title" placeholder="Book Title" valueBinding="model.title"}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="book_author" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          {{input class="form-control" id="book_author" placeholder="Author" valueBinding="model.author"}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="book_amazon_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Amazon ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          {{input class="form-control" id="book_amazon_id" placeholder="Amazon ID" valueBinding="model.amazon_id"}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="book_review" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Review</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          {{textarea valueBinding="model.review" class="form-control" id="book_review"}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="book_rating" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Rating</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          {{view Ember.Select content=ratings valueBinding='model.rating' class="form-control" id="book_rating"}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="book_genre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Genre</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          {{view Ember.Select content=genres optionLabelPath="content.name" valueBinding="model.genre" class="form-control" id="book_genre"}}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" {{action 'createReview'}}>Save Review</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  {{book-details book=model}}
</div>
```

**app/routes/reviews/new.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      book: this.store.createRecord('book'),
      genres: this.store.findAll('genre')
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model.book);
    controller.set('genres', model.genres);
  },
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      if(this.currentModel.book.get('isNew')) {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to abandon progress?")) {
          this.currentModel.book.destroyRecord();
        } else {
          transition.abort();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**app/controllers/reviews/new.js**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  ratings: [5,4,3,2,1],
  actions: {
    createReview: function() {
      var controller = this;
      this.get('model').save().then(function() {
        controller.transitionToRoute('books');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This is the complete code in case it helps: https://github.com/FranGoitia/reading-list

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures are hardcoded data so trying to save them isnt going to work.
They are not in a database, they are in a file - https://github.com/FranGoitia/reading-list/blob/master/app/models/book.js.
Have you set up a database to save your models to?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. The strange thing is that I was doing this thing following a screencast on codeschool about Ember and they were able to save records using a Fixture Adapter.
I have to connect it with a Rails api for example and it will work.

Comment: Yeah, if you want models to persist you need to have some backend support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ember-cli then try [ember-cli-mirage](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage). 
In ember-cli-mirage you can have fixture like data but it is accessible via dummy APIs. You can actually store data as long as your app is running.